# Sequelize not connect with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

file config/config.json

```
{
    "development": {
        "username": "root",
        "password": null,
        "database": "example",
        "host": "example.sqlite",
        "dialect": "sqlite"
    },
    "stage": {
        "username": "db_user",
        "password": "db_password",
        "database": "db_name",
        "host": "localhost",
        "dialect": "mysql"
    },
    "production": {
        "username": "root",
        "password": null,
        "database": "example",
        "host": "example.sqlite",
        "dialect": "sqlite"
    }
}
```

file models/index.js

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db = {};

if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
    var match = process.env.DATABASE_URL.match(/postgres:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@([^:]+):(\d+)\/(.+)/);
    sequelize = new Sequelize(match[5], match[1], match[2], {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        protocol: 'postgres',
        port: match[4],
        host: match[3],
        logging: true //false
    })

} else {
    var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function(file) {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
        var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

I'm test with Postgres on heroku, it's work. https://warm-plateau-49175.herokuapp.com/

I need to change to MySQL, it DOES NOT WORK. Definitely with the username and password is correct

Unhandled rejection SequelizeAccessDeniedError: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[image]

test mysql
[image]

Comment: are you able to connect mysql client with same credentials?

Comment: yes, it's connect via command line mysql